# symfony2: unable to persist entity and insert into database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm new to Symfony2, so please help me to solve it. Have entity Report and entity Organization.

Report mapping looks like:

```
 <entity name="Acme\ReportsBundle\Entity\Report" table="reports_report">
    <lifecycle-callbacks>
        <lifecycle-callback type="prePersist" method="setCreatedAt"/>
        <lifecycle-callback type="prePersist" method="setUpdatedAt"/>
    </lifecycle-callbacks>
        <many-to-one field="organization" target-entity="Acme\OrganizationBundle\Entity\Organization" inversed-by="reports">
        <join-column name="organization_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
        </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one field="year" target-entity="Acme\ReportsBundle\Entity\Year" inversed-by="reports">
        <join-column name="year_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
    </many-to-one>
    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
        <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id> 
    <field name="organization_id" type="integer" lenght="11" nullable="false" />
    <field name="year_id" type="integer" lenght="11" nullable="false" />
    <field name="status" type="smallint" nullable="true" />
    <field name="user_created" type="integer" lenght="11" nullable="false" />
    <field name="user_updated" type="integer" lenght="11" nullable="false" />
    <field name="created_at" type="datetime" nullable="false" />
    <field name="updated_at" type="datetime" nullable="false" />
</entity>
```

and Organization part:

```
 /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Acme\ReportsBundle\Entity\Report", mappedBy="organizations")
     * 
     */
    protected $reports;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->reports = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
```

I'm trying set Report properties using constructor:
Acme\ReportsBundle\Entity\Report

```
public function __construct(\Acme\OrganizationBundle\Entity\Organization $organization, \Acme\ReportsBundle\Entity\Year $year, \Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User $user)
    {
       $this->organization_id = $organization->getId();

       $this->year_id = $year->getId();

       $this->user_created = $user->getId();

       $this->user_updated = $user->getId();

    }
```

And finally controller
Acme/ReportsBundle/Controller/DefaultController:

```
public function indexCreate()
    {
        $organization = $this->getDoctrine()
             ->getRepository('AcmeOrganizationBundle:Organization')
             ->find(2);

        $year = $this->getDoctrine()
             ->getRepository('AcmeReportsBundle:Year')
             ->find(888);

        $user = $this->getDoctrine()
             ->getRepository('ApplicationSonataUserBundle:User')
             ->find(20);

            $report = new Report($organization, $year, $user);

            // var_dump shows that all properties were set

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $em->persist($report);

            $em->flush();

         }
```

So, visiting this route I get:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO reports_report (organization_id, year_id, status, user_created, user_updated, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, null, 20, 20, "2014-09-21 15:07:41", "2014-09-21 15:07:41"]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'organization_id' cannot be null
```

So, whats wrong with properties whitch were set using constructor? Why user_id was persisted, but organization_id and year_id not?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it myself. Solution was not to set Report organization_id or year_id manually, but only referencing properties ($organization, $year) in constructor.
Acme/ReportBundle/Entity/Report.php constructor should look like:

```
public function __construct(\Acme\OrganizationBundle\Entity\Organization $organization, \Acme\ReportsBundle\Entity\Year $year, \Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User $user)
    {

       $this-organization = $organization;
       $this->year = $year;
       $this->user_created = $user->getId();
       $this->user_updated = $user->getId();    
       $this->status = 2;




}
```